# Keep track of launches bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I found some threads that discuss this and implemented it into my code, however I'm having an error.

I am trying to do something every 5th launch.

Also the code sets `launchAmounts`, is that built in into `userDefaults`, or do I have to declare this somewhere?

I am doing this from `viewwillappear` in my main view controller.

```
NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger appLaunchAmounts = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"LaunchAmounts"];
appLaunchAmounts = appLaunchAmounts %5;
NSLog(@"app has been launched = %d", appLaunchAmounts);
[userDefaults setInteger:appLaunchAmounts+1 forKey:@"LaunchAmounts"];


if (appLaunchAmounts==0) {
```

Comment: Why `appLaunchAmounts = appLaunchAmounts %5`?

Comment: i guess its redundant?  should it just be if(applaunchamounts%5==0){...?

Comment: i'm running the simulator, does that mean that it will not track the uses?

Comment: it will only track from 1 - 5 and 1- 5 again

Comment: All seems fine... Any error/warning messages? btw, did you do [userDefaults synchronize]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks like it should work, except for the fact that you have it in viewWillAppear. That method could be called many times in one run if you're switching back and forth between different view controllers. You should put it in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method in the app delegate.

What's not working the way you have it now?

Comment: you are right, I just had to move it there to work.  Thanks.  Learning quickly :)